# Summation of a double series (i+j)

Tags: summation

I want to compute this to closed form:

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^i (i+j).$$

After the first series I got:

$$\frac12(3i^2 + i)$$

After the second series I got:
$$\frac12n(n+1)^2$$

Can someone please confirm if this right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have the same result:
$$
\frac{n(n+1)^2}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i (i+j)=\sum_{i=1}^n (i^2+i\cdot(i+1)/2)=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2+\sum_{i=1}^n i\cdot (i+1)/2$$
$$=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}+\dfrac{n(n+1)}{4}$$
$$=\dfrac{n(n+1)^2}{2}$$